# How to recreate this Header?

Tags: header-footer

https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/0956797617714579

What package is required to make the line on the header?[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You may contact APS for instructions for publishing an article in their publications.  Hopeful they provide LaTeX  template for this.

Comment: the file was made with InDesign not tex, but you can draw a line with `\hrule` you don't need any specific package.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

If you want just a line as broad as the text width, you can use just a horizontal line like:

```
\hrule
```

Or you can use a custom length and width `\rule` command:

```
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
```

This line gives you the same output as previous. Here, `\textwidth` is the length of line and `0.4pt` is the width of line.

You can customize it:

```
\rule{5cm}{0.4pt}
```

A full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Some text goes here. It needs some gap

\vspace{10pt} % <-- gap between line and text
\hrule

\vspace{10pt}
Some text goes here.

\noindent
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}

\vspace{10pt}
Some text goes here

\rule{5cm}{0.4pt} 

\end{document}
```